# Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object

Tags: yii2

I am trying to upload image and database table.

on database table basic_info field name 'photo' that i want to store file name.

here is model

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['photo'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['image'], 'safe'],
            [['image'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png'],
        ];
    }
```

here is controller

```
 public function actionCreate()
        {
            $model = new BasicInfo();


           if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
            {

                $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
                $filename = pathinfo($model->image , PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $ext = pathinfo($model->image , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                $newFname = $filename.'.'.$ext;
                $path=Yii::getAlias('@membersImgPath');

                    if(!empty($newFname)){
                        $model->image->saveAs($path.$newFname);
                        $model->image = $newFname;
                        if($model->save()){
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                        }
                    }

                }
                    return $this->render('create', [
                        'model' => $model,
                ]);
        }
```

here is view

```
echo FileInput::widget([
    'name' => 'photo', 
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
]);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: are you posting the file as well? can you post the secion containing `ActiveForm::begin`?

Comment: So... Check what `$model->image` returns. Does Your form has `enctype` param set? Follow guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html

Comment: yes,i am set enctype.how to check $model->image

Comment: Like all variables, `var_dump($var);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your comment here,

> $form = ActiveForm::begin(['type'=>ActiveForm::TYPE_VERTICAL],['opti‌​ons'=>['enctype'=>'m‌​ultipart/form-data']‌​]);

`ActiveForm::begin` does not have a second parameter. you need to use a **single** options array.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'type'    => ActiveForm::TYPE_VERTICAL,
    'opti‌​ons' => [
        'enctype' => 'm‌​ultipart/form-data'
    ]‌
​]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to check if there's a file. To do it try:

```
if(UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image')) {
     // here should go your code with $model->image
}
```

Youre using `pathinfo` to get filename and extension. Remember, that youre using powerfull framework, you just initialized class `UploadedFile` which can do everything for you:

```
if(UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image')) {
     $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
     $newFname = $model->image->name;     // UploadedFile have properties like `name`, `tempName`, even `size`!
}
```

After doing this small fixes to your code (you should always check if something is set) - we can go to main problem.

Your input field name is `photo`, but youre trying to get image with name `image`.

Change this:

```
UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
```

To this:

```
UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');   // remeber to change it in `if` statement aswell!!
```

Theres also posibility that youre trying to upload file bigger than your `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` allows. Change this properties in your `php.ini`, restart server and try again. If still something is not right, try to debug this thing, for start by doing `var_dump($_FILES);die;` in your controller.